# How do you enter comments to existing Stackoverflow answers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I have questions about the answer at link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7029210 but I have not been able to figure any way to enter comments although other people seem to have no problem doing so.  Can any provide any guidance on this?

Comment: In your case you could possibly ask a new question and reference the link to the old answer, just as you've done here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a reputation of at least 50 to comment on other people's questions.

See

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges

https://stackoverflow.com/faq